# hadoop datanode rack awareness setting

Tags: hadoop

I am building a hadoop cluster. I have 3 racks, each rack consists several virtual machines. 
How to config hadoop to let it have rack awareness? Some suggest using "topology.script.file.name" to set a script?

Can you write me an working example of doing it?

For example:

```
rack1: 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3 
rack2: 192.168.1.4, 192.168.1.5, 192.168.1.6 
rack3: 192.168.1.7, 192.168.1.8, 192.168.1.9
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give them other subnets, like rack1 192.168.1.*, rack2 192.168.2.* and so on. Hadoop will recognize this.

Comment: where to set this? Can you give me some example please?

Comment: In your DNS / hosts configuration. This is a server setup.

Comment: Really? In /etc/hosts file? Hadoop can recongnize this?

Comment: sure. How do you think he is going to manage the communication?